# How do I make python selenium use a proxychain

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, tor, proxychains

How can I configure a web browser preferably chrome in python selenium with a standard VPN/Proxy connection that is then routed through the Tor service to make websites work that don't allow tor connections?

In my research, I discovered that Selenium intentionally does not support proxychains. However, I'm exploring the possibility of configuring Selenium to connect to a standard local proxy on my machine, which would then establish a connection to the Tor service. Can anyone provide guidance on how to set up this kind of proxy chain with Selenium and Tor for web scraping or testing purposes?